# How Can I toggle the background color of different buttons and add slide in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I have three `button` in my app and i want to toggle the background color of red when I click one of them, and I also want them to slide in a direction. The first button should have default color of red and when i click on the second button the first one should lose the styles and second one should transition left to right in background red.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const TopOptions = () => {

  const addStyles = () => {
    const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col border-b shadow-lg">
        <div className="flex flex-col px-4">
          <p className="text-xs pl-6 pt-4">PUNE</p>
          <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
            <svg
              className="h-3 w-3"
              id="Capa_1"
              enable-background="new 0 0 512 512"
              height="512"
              viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              width="512"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <g id="XMLID_1056_">
                <g id="XMLID_191_">
                  <path
                    id="XMLID_192_"
                    d="m86 92.33c2.63 0 5.21-1.061 7.07-2.931 1.86-1.859 2.93-4.439 2.93-7.069s-1.07-5.21-2.93-7.07-4.44-2.93-7.07-2.93-5.21 1.069-7.07 2.93c-1.86 1.86-2.93 4.44-2.93 7.07s1.07 5.21 2.93 7.069c1.86 1.871 4.44 2.931 7.07 2.931z"
                  />
                  <path
                    id="XMLID_261_"
                    d="m130.33 92.33c2.63 0 5.21-1.061 7.07-2.931 1.87-1.859 2.93-4.439 2.93-7.069s-1.06-5.21-2.93-7.07c-1.86-1.86-4.44-2.93-7.07-2.93s-5.2 1.069-7.07 2.93c-1.86 1.86-2.93 4.44-2.93 7.07s1.07 5.21 2.93 7.069c1.87 1.871 4.45 2.931 7.07 2.931z"
                  />
                  <path
                    id="XMLID_262_"
                    d="m174.67 92.33c2.63 0 5.2-1.061 7.07-2.931 1.86-1.859 2.93-4.439 2.93-7.069s-1.07-5.21-2.93-7.07-4.44-2.93-7.07-2.93-5.21 1.069-7.08 2.93c-1.86 1.86-2.92 4.44-2.92 7.07s1.06 5.21 2.92 7.069c1.87 1.871 4.45 2.931 7.08 2.931z"
                  />
                  <path
                    id="XMLID_265_"
                    d="m512 206.959v-24.959c0-1.252-.235-2.492-.693-3.657l-21.307-54.231v-54.112c0-27.57-22.43-50-50-50h-368c-27.57 0-50 22.43-50 50v54.099l-21.308 54.245c-.457 1.165-.692 2.405-.692 3.656v24.959c0 17.065 8.529 31.512 22 39.97v225.071h-12c-5.523 0-10 4.478-10 10s4.477 10 10 10h470 22c5.523 0 10-4.478 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10h-12v-225.071c13.471-8.458 22-22.905 22-39.97zm-51 27.999c-17.962 0-31-11.775-31-27.999v-.001-14.958h62v14.959c0 16.224-13.038 27.999-31 27.999zm-51-28c0 16.225-13.038 28-31 28s-31-11.775-31-28v-14.958h62zm-82 0c0 16.225-13.038 28-31 28s-31-11.775-31-28v-14.958h62zm-82 0c0 16.225-13.038 28-31 28s-31-11.775-31-28v-14.958h62zm-82 0c0 16.225-13.038 28-31 28s-31-11.775-31-28v-14.958h62zm-125.187-70.958h434.369l14.144 36h-462.654zm33.187-96h368c16.542 0 30 13.458 30 30v46h-428v-46c0-16.542 13.458-30 30-30zm-52 152h62v14.958.001c0 16.224-13.038 27.999-31 27.999s-31-11.775-31-27.999zm70 280v-169.042h108v169.042zm380 0h-252v-179.042c0-5.522-4.477-10-10-10h-128c-5.523 0-10 4.478-10 10v179.042h-28v-217.737c2.91.449 5.911.695 9 .695 17.181 0 31.861-7.208 41-18.75 9.139 11.542 23.819 18.75 41 18.75s31.861-7.208 41-18.75c9.139 11.542 23.819 18.75 41 18.75s31.861-7.208 41-18.75c9.139 11.542 23.819 18.75 41 18.75s31.861-7.208 41-18.75c9.139 11.542 23.819 18.75 41 18.75 17.18 0 31.861-7.208 41-18.75 9.139 11.542 23.819 18.75 41 18.75 3.089 0 6.09-.246 9-.695z"
                  />
                  <path
                    id="XMLID_321_"
                    d="m120 384.479c-2.63 0-5.21 1.07-7.07 2.931-1.86 1.859-2.93 4.439-2.93 7.069s1.07 5.21 2.93 7.07 4.44 2.93 7.07 2.93 5.21-1.069 7.07-2.93 2.93-4.44 2.93-7.07-1.07-5.21-2.93-7.069c-1.86-1.86-4.44-2.931-7.07-2.931z"
                  />
                  <path
                    id="XMLID_415_"
                    d="m432 282.958h-41.936c-5.523 0-10 4.478-10 10s4.477 10 10 10h31.936v105.042h-156v-105.042h34.063c5.523 0 10-4.478 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10h-44.063c-5.523 0-10 4.478-10 10v125.042c0 5.522 4.477 10 10 10h176c5.523 0 10-4.478 10-10v-125.042c0-5.522-4.477-10-10-10z"
                  />
                  <path
                    id="XMLID_788_"
                    d="m345.06 302.96c2.64 0 5.21-1.07 7.07-2.931 1.87-1.859 2.93-4.439 2.93-7.069 0-2.641-1.06-5.21-2.93-7.07-1.86-1.87-4.43-2.93-7.07-2.93-2.63 0-5.21 1.06-7.07 2.93-1.86 1.86-2.93 4.43-2.93 7.07 0 2.63 1.07 5.21 2.93 7.069 1.86 1.861 4.44 2.931 7.07 2.931z"
                  />
                </g>
              </g>
            </svg>
            <select className="pl-2">
              <option value="Kothrud Outlet">Kothrud Outlet</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className=" bg-gray-100 my-5 text-center flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly text-sm rounded-md mx-4">
          <button
            className="w-full py-3  rounded-md shadow text-white font-bold btn"
            onClick={addStyles}
          >
            DELIVERY
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={addStyles}
            className="w-full py-3 font-bold text-gray-600 btn"
          >
            TAKEAWAY
          </button>
          <button className="w-full py-3 font-bold text-gray-600">
            DINE IN
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TopOptions;
```